# How to use COUNT() and SUM() in 1 query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the sum of students marks and also number of students

Table schema is

```
Stud_ID|Stud_Name|Marks|Class
1      | A       |20   |1   
1      | A       |10   |1
1      | A       |22   |1
5      | G       |21   |1
5      | G       |16   |1
5      | G       |27   |1
2      | B       |13   |1
2      | B       |14   |1
2      | B       |21   |1
2      | B       |13   |1
2      | B       |21   |1
3      | C       |10   |1
3      | C       |17   |1
3      | C       |16   |1
```

I need Total of Marks of each students and also how many students are there in table. I am trying combine DISTINCT AND SUM both but not worked

```
SELECT count(
sum(`mark`) FROM `es_marks_entry_summery` where `class` ='16' group by `Stud_ID`)
```

Comment: You need to use two queries to get sum of each table and to count all students [*see fiddle demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8092/2)

Comment: no you dont.. it can be done in one single select.. see my answer. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4baed/4

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (
    select stud_id, sum(mark) as mark
    from es_marks_entry_summery
    where class = '16'
    group by stud_id
) t1, (
    select count(distinct stud_id) as student_count
    from es_marks_entry_summery
    where class = '16'
) t2
```

Comment: @T I Thank you. But query is showing 117 students where as there are only 38 students records in table, but each students may have 5 to 6 records. I need total number of students that is 38 and total of marks of each students. You first part of the query is return correct summation of mark, but second part is showing 117 I need 38 because in class 1 there are 38 studnets

Comment: Are you using the write column in the count distinct? Have you change the query in anyway?

Comment: you just need a WHERE to filter out the other classes... after "t2" add WHERE class = your_specific_class_number

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE (Stud_ID INT, Marks INT)

INSERT INTO @Result(Stud_ID, Marks) SELECT COUNT(Stud_ID), SUM(Marks) from es_marks_entry_summery WHERE Class = '16'

SELECT * FROM @Result
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    name, 
    SUM(marks) as total_marks, 
    (select count(distinct id) FROM t WHERE class = 16) as num_students
FROM t
GROUP BY id
```

see the sample fiddle here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4baed/4

you can then filter by class or however you need to customize it with a `WHERE` clause

if you also want it to be the unique number of students per class with their marks then just change the `GROUP BY` to this

```
GROUP BY id, class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select *  from (select class ,Stud_ID, sum(Marks) as Marks from tbl  group by Stud_ID) tbl1, (select count(distinct Stud_ID) as Times from tbl) tbl2
    where Class=16;
```

See example in fiddle :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/10701